# How do I retrieve an out parameter from a MySQL Stored Procedure in Python using MySQL-Connector?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm having trouble accessing an out parameters values from a stored procedure in MySQL(8x) using Python(3.7) and sql connector (8x).

My stored procedure is an update procedure and it is working, however I don't know how to get the out value in code.

Here is my stored procedure...I simply want to access the out parameter named *success* in python.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_due_date`(param_bookId int, param_cardNumber int, param_dueDate date, out success int)
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl_book_loans
    SET dueDate = param_dueDate
    WHERE bookId = param_bookId and cardNo = param_cardNumber;        
    SET success = 777666;    
END
```

Here is my python function (python 3.7), I just don't know what method to call on the cursor object, or
how to approach this.  The for loop also doesn't print anything, I'm assuming because the cursor stored results are empty.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
def updateDueDate(bookId, cardNo, newDueDate):
    args = [bookId, cardNo, newDueDate, 0]

    myCursor.callproc(
        'update_due_date', args)
    myCursor.execute()

    for result in myCursor.stored_results():
        print(result.fetchall())
    cnx.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you the fourth parameter

See official [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html)

```
def updateDueDate(bookId, cardNo, newDueDate):
    args = [bookId, cardNo, newDueDate, 0]

    result_args = cursor.callproc('update_due_date', args)

    print(result_args[3])
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be result_args[3] ?

Comment: Test it please, I think that it is correct with 4

Comment: I have tested it in my own code, all the time. Your _args_ and _result_args_ are just python lists, which are indexed from zero, so the fourth parameter is at index 3. You pass _args_ into `callproc()` with a placeholder value (zero in your example) for the OUT parameter, and it returns the parameter list with the OUT parameter updated to the value assigned to it by the sproc, but it's still the fourth parameter so it's still at index 3, and `print(results_args[3])` is correct; your version will throw an IndexError: list index out of range exception because there is no list item at index 4.

Comment: I changed it to 3 TT Hank you