# How can I resolve this error 1241 error that the stored procedure throwing?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mariadb-10.4

In python 3.x, I have a class with this definition

```
     def sproc(self, sql, *args):
          self.__open()
          self.__session.callproc(sql, args)
          number_rows = self.__session.rowcount
          number_columns = len(self.__session.description)

          if number_rows >= 1 and number_columns > 1:
               result = [item for item in self.__session.fetchall()]
          else:
               result = [item[0] for item in self.__session.fetchall()]
          self.__close
          return result
```

In my workhorse.py script, I've definition that call `sproc`.

```
def tradepl(user_id, play_entry_id, play_exit_id):
    try:
        db_cnx = db(dbconfig.database_configuration['host']
        , dbconfig.database_configuration['user']
        , dbconfig.database_configuration['password']
        , dbconfig.database_configuration['database'])

        args = (user_id, play_entry_id, play_exit_id)
        result = db_cnx.sproc('lastpl', args)
        return result

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

The lastpl is a stored procedure that has the following:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE lastPl (user_id int, play_entry_id int, play_exit_id int, OUT profit_dollar decimal(10,2), OUT profit_percent decimal(10,2), OUT days_in_trade int)
BEGIN

/**** get profit and loss data from the closing trade ****/

    select
    case p1.entry_transaction_type when 'sto' then (p1.entry_cost - p2.exit_cost)
                else (p2.exit_cost - p1.entry_cost)
                END profit_dollar
    , case p1.entry_transaction_type when 'sto' then (((p1.entry_cost - p2.exit_cost)/p1.entry_cost) * 100)
                else (((p2.exit_cost - p1.entry_cost)/p1.entry_cost) * 100)
                END profit_percent
    , datediff(p1.entry_date, p2.exit_date) days_in_trade
    from play_entry p1
    join play_exit p2
        on p1.play_entry_id = p2.play_entry_id
    where p1.user_id = user_id
    and p1.play_entry_id = play_entry_id
    and p2.play_exit_id = play_exit_id;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

When I call the tradepl definition i'm given the error:

```
output = tradepl(user_id[0], play_entry_id[0], play_exit_id)
for row in output:
    profit_dollar = row[0]
    profit_percent = row[1]
    day_in_trade = row[2]
```

`(1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')`
`'NoneType' object is not iterable`

I have spent about 5 hours on this whole process and pretty much exhausted.  The search results that come up on google/duckduck doesn't match up to what i'm trying to accomplish.

any help would be greatly appreciated.  thx

Comment: the way i'm calling it is

```
output = tradepl(user_id[0], play_entry_id[0], play_exit_id)
for row in output:
    profit_dollar = row[0]
    profit_percent = row[1]
    day_in_trade = row[2]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what is happening to you, however [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61977745/4637583) is an answer to question where someone was having trouble getting their result from calling a stored procedure.

Comment: @alan, I can get it working inside the definition like the example you linked me to.  But in my case, i have my own class and like to make the call thru there.

Comment: what happens if you change ` args = (user_id, play_entry_id, play_exit_id)` to ` args = (user_id, play_entry_id, play_exit_id,0,0,0)` in `tradepl()`

Comment: o man, that might be it.  i'm trying now.

Comment: nope ... still same message in the console.  additionally, i got this error: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: I'm questioning the necessity if the `*` here `def sproc(self, sql, *args):` to unpack that tuple.

Comment: i wrote that so it would be generic enough to use against other sprocs.  I had tried using an orderedict against it (*arg) and casting it as tuple but it still gave the same error.

Comment: I went back to using dynamic sql stmt to get this working and avoid having to use the sproc.  it seem such a pita compare to other programming lng.  I'll revisit it when some of my other experience developers return and I can pick their brain in real time.  thanks for the help.